# Using Virtual PC to check compatibility

Tags: c#, wpf, virtual-machine

Is a Virtual PC acceptable for determining your application compatibility? For example, running a Virtual PC on Windows 7 to check compatibility of XP, Vista, and Windows 8. If it works on the virtual machine, is it safe to say that it will most likely work on that platform?

Comment: That's what we do. It has worked well so far.

Comment: Yes, Virtual Machines will behave the same a physical machines when it comes to the OS

Comment: The MSDN has [a entire section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee943321.aspx) devoted to setting up automated testing with virtual machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of testing with Virtual PC, I'd say that it is pretty reliable to check the compatibility of your programs.

When dealing with registry values or driver specific hardware, sometimes the programs do not function the same on a Virtual PC.